# How do I record audio from a voice channel with a discord bot in python

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx: commands.Context):
    channel: discord.VoiceChannel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is not None:
        return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)
    await channel.connect(cls=NativeVoiceClient)
    await ctx.invoke(client.get_command('rec'))

@client.command()
async def rec(ctx):
    ctx.voice_client.record(lambda e: print(f"Exception: {e}"))
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Started the Recording!",
                             description="use !stop to stop!", color=0x546e7a)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client.is_recording():
        return
    await ctx.send(f'Stopping the Recording')

    wav_bytes = await ctx.voice_client.stop_record()

    name = str(random.randint(000000, 999999))
    with open(f'{name}.wav', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(wav_bytes)
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

I tried this but it doesnt stop recording nor does it send me any audio files. How do i fix this or is there a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all

> ctx.voice_client.record(lambda e: print(f"Exception: {e}"))

This line cannot be done, since this method no longer exsists.
I don't have an example but look at this image, it shows what a channel has of options currently.

I can tell you that, most likely you want to look into some combination,
Of opus,ffmpeg, readable, audio stream. But how to do this is currently beyond my understanding atm.

voice channel
https://imgur.com/a/7i1zQHo

and here is voice client
https://imgur.com/a/ZMDXgqt

Comment: "look at this image" what image? Is that one of the images below?